# POST REQUEST _CastError (type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Tags: image, post, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been struggling for days trying to make this thing work. 
This POST method is to upload an image which should be a "File" and a caption.
The API requires:

```
PAYLOAD:
- caption
- image
HEADER
- AUTHENTICATION
```

I'm new to flutter and I've followed a lot of tutorials but nothing seems to work.

here's my code:

```
 static Future<void> addPost(
      BuildContext context, String caption, File image) async {
    debugPrint("$image");
    String imageFile = image.path.split("/").last;
    debugPrint("$imageFile");
    Utils().showRegisterProgressDialog(context);
    final userData = {
      "caption": caption,
      "image" : image 
    };

    final response = await http.post(
        APIServices.HTTP_DOMAIN + APIServices.POST_ADD_NEW,
        body: userData,
        headers: {"Authentication": "Bearer " + Constants.token});
    debugPrint("STATUS: ${response.statusCode}");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Utils().hidePostingDialog(context);
      Utils().postSuccessDialog(context);
    } else {
      Utils().hidePostingDialog(context);
      Utils().postErrorDialog(context);
    }

    print(response.body);

    return response;
  }
```

I'd appreciate any help and suggestions.

**EDIT**

I've also tried using  `MultipartRequest` but it returns a statuscode of `500`

here's my code:

```
static Future<void> addPost(
      BuildContext context, String caption, File image) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Authentication": "Bearer ${Constants.token}"
    };
    debugPrint("TOKEN : $headers");
    Utils().showPostingDialog(context);
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image.openRead()));
    var length = await image.length();
    var url =
        Uri.parse("${APIServices.HTTP_DOMAIN}${APIServices.POST_ADD_NEW}");

    debugPrint("TOKEN : $stream");
    debugPrint("TOKEN : $length");
    debugPrint("TOKEN : $url");
    final request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
    debugPrint("TOKEN : $request");
    debugPrint("TOKEN : $image");
    debugPrint("TOKEN : ${image.path}");
    var multipartFile =
        new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length, filename: image.path);
    debugPrint("TOKEN : ${multipartFile.contentType}");
    request.fields['caption'] = caption;
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();
    debugPrint("TOKEN : ${response.request}");
    print(response.statusCode);

    // listen for response
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Http error 500 is generally seen during a bad request.
I would recommend you to try the exact same request using Postman and see what the result is, you can also try and print the response.message which sometimes can tell you what you did wrong while formatting the request.

Some more advice: try using the DIO package, it is much simpler to format request in it, you can set the header once, also errors are properly formatted, and a bunch of more advanced features are available which are quite helpful.